# Sw architecture - Comunication between java modules

Tags: java, maven, ejb

I have to make an app in java defined in a multi module maven project that will be executed in a jboss server.

The app's modules will be defined in the parent pom file this way:

```
.................
<module>dbModule</module>
<module>securityModule</module>
<module>auditoryModule</module>
..........
```

And the question is :
How can be made the comunication btw modules?With ejbs?Is there any sample?

Thanks!

Comment: Will they be deployed as part of the same EAR or WAR ?

Comment: yes they will be in same war

Answer (score 1):

Deploy them as EAR (Enterprise Application Archive)

> EAR: All .jar and .war are packaged as JAR file with
>   .ear (enterprise archive) extension and deployed into Application
>   Server.

The modules within the EAR can easily communicate with each other.